# Upgrading Spring boot version to version 3. Problem with javax.cache library

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade spring boot from 2.7.x to 3.0.1. The last thing I have left to upgrade is the library.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
   <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Have any of you had a similar problem? I didn't see any information on how to do this in the guide.

Comment: Remove that dependency and use `spring-boot-starter-cache` instead, that will give you the proper version of the dependency. Prefer starters over individual dependencies or at least ditch the `version` tag so Spring Boot manages the version.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this dependency and use from spring boot starters.
This is already having Vulnerabilities from dependencies:CVE-2020-15250.[MVN REPO CACHE 1.1.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api/1.1.1)